# Why won't this PHP string escape right?

Tags: php

This works:

```
$command = "convert C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\a.jpg -resize 40x30 ^ C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\a-thumb.jpg";

exec($command);
```

Since I am using double quotes I thought this would work too:

```
    $command = "convert C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\$file_name.jpg -resize 40x30 ^ C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\$file_name-thumb.jpg";

    exec($command);
```

but the `$file_name` var isn't being recorgnized as such but it seen as a string for some reason.

So I tried this:

```
$command = "convert C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\".$file_name.".jpg -resize 40x30 ^ C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\".$file_name."-thumb.jpg";

exec($command);
```

But this throws a bunch of syntax errors.

How to escape this string properly? By escape I just mean how can I use this with the variable `$file_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to rules:

```
$command = "convert C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\{$file_name}.jpg -resize 40x30 ^ C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\{$file_name}-thumb.jpg";
exec($command);
```

or:

```
$command = "convert C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\%s.jpg -resize 40x30 ^ C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\%s-thumb.jpg";
exec(sprintf($command, $filename, $filename));
```

Comment: @JakeRow123 Out of curiousity, to get the second one to work did you use $file_name instead or $filename in sprintf?

Comment: @Bryan yeah I had to  change the variable name to $file_name, it was a typo on the answerer's part.

Answer (score 1):

No you should use single quotes for it to escape properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add brackets to make it work:

```
$command = "convert C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\{$file_name}.jpg -resize 40x30 ^ C:\wamp\www\site\uploads\{$file_name}-thumb.jpg";
```